# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: No such recipient.But email is sent

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'am getting an error while trying to send email using StmpClient.
Error:

Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: No such recipient

But the strange thing is that, the email is sent.My destination email recive the whole and comlete mensage.

Any ideas of what it could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the code I can only guess, but the first thing that comes to mind is that the from address doesn't exist on the server that's sending the mail

Comment: but how could the email server send the email if he does't know the email destination(RCPT)? It's not my email server, neither on my system that error is printing..it's on the client server....and at least for now its the only message i have acess...thx by the way

Comment: The "from" address is probably nonexistent. Not the destination, but the source.